# How to continue download multiple files (AWS server images) in background in react-native iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-fs, ios-background-mode

I created an app where user can download multiple images on one click using react-native-fs which is working perfectly in Android. But in iOS when app is inactive then download stopped and user have to start download again.

```
async.eachSeries(DownloadData, async function (tourData, finish) {
    console.log("# resumable : 655612", tourData);
    var fileExtension = '';
    var fileURL = tourData.path;
var fileExtension = "/" + tourData.name + "Image" + p + ".png
     p = p + 1;
    const downloadDest = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + fileExtension;
    let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
    var v = dirs.DocumentDir;
    var jobId = -1;

    const ret = RNFS.downloadFile({
        fromUrl: encodeURI(fileURL),
        toFile: downloadDest,
        connectionTimeout: 1000 * 10,
        readTimeout: 1000 * 10,
        background: true,
        discretionary: true,
        progressDivider: 1,
        resumable: (res) => {
            console.log("# resumable", res);
        },
        begin: (res) => {
         console.log(res)
        },
        progress: (data) => {
           console.log(data)
        },
    });

    jobId = ret.jobId;

    RNFS.isResumable(jobId).then(true);

    if (await RNFS.isResumable(jobId)) {
        console.log("# resumable : # resumable : # resumable :",jobId);
        RNFS.resumeDownload(jobId)
    }
    ret.promise.then((res) => {
       finish();
   }).catch(err => {
       finish();
   })
```

},function (err) {
    if (!err) {
        callback(true)
    } else {
     callback(false) 
    }
}));

Answer (score 0):

Running download in background in IOS require few extra settings check this section https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs#background-downloads-tutorial-ios 
they also mentioned that IOS will give you 30 sec after handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession

`BE AWARE! iOS will give about 30 sec. to run your code after handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession is called and until completionHandler is triggered so don't do anything that might take a long time (like unzipping), you will be able to do it after the user re-launces the app, otherwide iOS will terminate your app.`

I hope this helps